# Bulk inserts and INSERT INTO IGNORE with CrateDB

Tags: sql, cratedb

I'd like to insert huge amounts of data, What should I use: Single `insert into` statements, or do I have to use bulk inserts? Is there something else? The reason I ask is, that my CrateDB node's disk is only busy at 11kb/s on average while the disk load is at 100% using single inserts!

Furthermore, is something like `INSERT INTO IGNORE` supported? Can I just throw my data in bulk at CrateDB and it will ignore duplicate entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you rightly guessed, bulk inserts give you the best performance. However the experience might vary - which mostly depends on the chosen "bulk size", i.e. how many records are sent at once. Usually a batch of 1000 records performs very well, but it's recommended to play around a bit since this might be specific to the hardware CrateDB runs on.

Bulk inserts will also skip duplicate inserts automatically - if you have a primary key defined on that table (how else would the DB know what's a duplicate?). This comes at a performance impact (needless lookup/failed insert) though...

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should consider using [insert or update](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/reference/insert.html#on-duplicate-key-update)